# Java script disabled and onbeforeunload event

Tags: javascript, browser

I would like to know if there is a method to intercept onbeforeunload event and consequently do some action in a browser that have java script execution disabled.

Thank You

Piercarlo

Comment: What language would that action be written in?

Comment: Did you read your own question?  Javascript is disabled and you want to program some action in javascript?

Comment: @Barmar Javascript of course :)

Answer (score 2):

If Javascript is disabled, you won't be able to use Javascript, so you can't intercept anything.

Also, I feel like there's a need for disambiguation here. You say

> java script

so it seems that you may be confusing the Java programming language, with Javascript, which despite sharing 4 letters, are completely different beasts.

Check this old question for more information, and a bunch of geeky jokes on the subject.

[What's the difference between JavaScript and Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java)